# Is there a limit \ max-length for <jsp:param>?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, jakarta-ee, jsp-tags

I have to include a jsp into another. In the parent jsp there are lot of variables and values i wish to be included in included-jsp, so I've used 
with . Wondering if there is any limit to how many params I can use.

Comment: Limited only by the HTTP spec that underlies it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather converting all the values to String to be passed as request parameters, directive include should be used. <%@ include file=